# How can I access request object in the wagtail Page model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail

I wanna dynamically set default value of the field to the currently logged in user:

```
class SimplePage(Page):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=request.user)
```

I know about `get_context`, but class attributes cannot call instance methods.

```
def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return {
        PAGE_TEMPLATE_VAR: self,
        'self': self,
        'request': request,
    }
```

Any more ideas?

Essentially whoever is logged in into the admin should become author's default.

Answer (score 1):

I got part way there but am not sure how to get the request context for the admin forms generated by the Wagtail `edit_handler` system.

### Overview

- Wagtail lets you [set a custom form](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#customising-generated-forms) for use within its admin, we do this by adding `base_form_class` to the page model, which will reference a new class that extends `WagtailAdminPageForm`.
- We then [provide initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) to the form by passing in an `initial` object to the super class's `__init__`.
- To get the auth model (for both relating it to the `SimplePage` model and when getting a default value we use Django's builtin auth/user helpers.

### Example

Note: Using Wagtail 2.0 import syntax.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm
#... other imports you should already have


class SimplePageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        auth_user_model = get_user_model()
        default_user = auth_user_model.objects.get(username='admin')
        initial = {
            'title': 'Unhelpful default title for the sake of example',
            'author_user': default_user
        }
        super().__init__(initial=initial, *args, **kwargs)


class SimplePage(Page):

    author_user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel('author_user')]

    base_form_class = SimplePageForm
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me some inspiration, but functionally the drop-down list is just as much hassle as typing the name manually.

Comment: Another idea - the page will have an attribute of `owner` set https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/d483c8d46543cd75caac8d8b4067173646072c81/wagtail/admin/views/pages.py#L184 so you can probably use that (but I imagine it will change with every request so you have to be careful to only ever set the page author if it’s not set already (so only ever recording the original author, not the user responsible for edits). You could use Django signals to hook into this. Idea credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/7668563/lo%C3%AFc-teixeira